# imported json data in notepad shows extra slash character.how to remove it

Tags: python, json, selenium

I am new to python so need help.
I have import Json data in notepad using python in selenium but getting extra slash character in output."This slash does not exist but after importing into text file it shows extra slash.Please suggest.

> {\"loginResponseCode\": \"1\", \"canChangePassword\": true,
>   \"isImpersonated\": false, \"suggestChangePassword\": )

Expected:

> {"loginResponseCode": "1", canchangepassword

My code:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\1.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsfun3, outfile,indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the backslashes are just for representing `"`.

Because python string is enclosed by " (or '), it needs extra backslash for representing `"` (or `'`) itself.

You don't have to care about `\`.

Comment: I need to remove slash since I need to compare result.I am QA so  I check if results are coming fine.

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work

```
json.dump(json.JSONDecoder().decode(jsfun3), outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'))
```